# Anyway to use Jquery to detect if Ajax loads certain HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A friend has a site on a platform where we cannot access the source code but can add our own JavaScript. Parts of the site load with Ajax.

I need to add an element when a particular piece of HTML loads. So far I've found:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $('.booking .simple_form input[type="submit"]').hide();
   $('.booking .simple_form').append('<a id="login-btn" href="#">Login</a>');
});
```

But because there are 4 pieces of content loaded by Ajax on the page, this element gets appended 4 times.

I've tried wrapping that in an if statement, eg:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  if ($('#login-btn').length) {
    $('.booking .simple_form input[type="submit"]').hide();
    $('.booking .simple_form').append('<a id="login-btn" href="#">Login</a>');
  }
});
```

But this doesn't work - nothing appears.

Would anyone know how to I can just add 1 button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong.

```
if ($('#login-btn').length) {
    $('.booking .simple_form input[type="submit"]').hide();
    $('.booking .simple_form').append('<a id="login-btn" href="#">Login</a>');
  }
```

Should be

```
if (!$('#login-btn').length) {
    $('.booking .simple_form input[type="submit"]').hide();
    $('.booking .simple_form').append('<a id="login-btn" href="#">Login</a>');
  }
```

When there are no elements, you have to check the falsy and then enter. add `!` before your condition.